# Could not launch AWS SAM application when using VS Code Debugger "Function not implemented"

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sam-cli, delve, aws-toolkit

I have a generic SAM application generated by AWS Toolkit.
My end goal is to debug my go application line by line.

Sorry if this question gets too long, but I have tried my best to add as few relevant details as possible, while trying to make sure I don't miss anything important.

I am using the default `launch.json` configurations generated by the Toolkit:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "sunflowers:HelloWorldFunction (go1.x)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {},
                "runtime": "go1.x"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "API sunflowers:HelloWorldFunction (go1.x)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "api",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
            },
            "api": {
                "path": "/hello",
                "httpMethod": "get",
                "payload": {
                    "json": {}
                }
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "go1.x"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I run `sunflowers:HelloWorldFunction (go1.x)`, I get the following error in the AWS Toolkit output:

```
could not launch process: fork/exec /var/task/hello-world: function not implemented
```

Full error Log:

```
2022-08-04 18:41:12 [INFO]: Preparing to debug locally: Lambda "hello-world"
2022-08-04 18:41:12 [INFO]: Building SAM application...
2022-08-04 18:41:12 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [/opt/homebrew/bin/sam build --build-dir /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output --template /Users/varungawande/playground/goLambdaDebug/sunflowers/template.yaml]
2022-08-04 18:41:13 [INFO]: Your template contains a resource with logical ID "ServerlessRestApi", which is a reserved logical ID in AWS SAM. It could result in unexpected behaviors and is not recommended.

2022-08-04 18:41:13 [INFO]: Building codeuri: /Users/varungawande/playground/goLambdaDebug/sunflowers/hello-world runtime: go1.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction

2022-08-04 18:41:13 [INFO]: Running GoModulesBuilder:Build

2022-08-04 18:41:13 [INFO]: 
Build Succeeded

2022-08-04 18:41:13 [INFO]: 
Built Artifacts  : ../../../../../private/tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output
Built Template   : ../../../../../private/tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output/template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Validate SAM template: sam validate
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke -t ../../../../../private/tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output/template.yaml
[*] Test Function in the Cloud: sam sync --stack-name {stack-name} --watch
[*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided --template-file ../../../../../private/tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output/template.yaml
        

2022-08-04 18:41:14 [INFO]: Build complete.
2022-08-04 18:41:14 [INFO]: Starting SAM application locally
2022-08-04 18:41:14 [INFO]: AWS.running.command
Invoking hello-world (go1.x)
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-go1.x:rapid-1.53.0-x86_64.

Mounting /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output/HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 8cc3eb7a-20f2-4599-81bc-2f29f8d02102 Version: $LATEST
API server listening at: [::]:5858
2022-08-04T13:11:16Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2022-08-04T13:11:16Z info layer=debugger launching process with args: [/var/task/hello-world]
2022-08-04 18:41:16 [INFO]: Waiting for SAM application to start...
could not launch process: fork/exec /var/task/hello-world: function not implemented
2022/08/04 13:11:16 exit status 1
04 Aug 2022 13:11:16,067 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 1 InvokeID=
API server listening at: [::]:5858
2022-08-04T13:11:16Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2022-08-04T13:11:16Z info layer=debugger launching process with args: [/var/task/hello-world]
could not launch process: fork/exec /var/task/hello-world: function not implemented
2022/08/04 13:11:16 exit status 1
END RequestId: 0dcb2785-a232-41aa-8f78-f61c82add96b
REPORT RequestId: 0dcb2785-a232-41aa-8f78-f61c82add96b  Init Duration: 1.26 ms  Duration: 838.60 ms Billed Duration: 839 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB 
2022-08-04 18:41:17 [INFO]: Attaching debugger to SAM application...

Command stopped: "sam local invoke"
2022-08-04 18:41:23 [ERROR]: Retry limit reached while trying to attach the debugger.
2022-08-04 18:41:23 [ERROR]: Unable to attach Debugger. Check AWS Toolkit logs. If it took longer than expected to start, you can still attach.
```

`sam local start-api` and `sam local invoke` still work.

The path they mounted at `/tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output/HelloWorldFunction` does have the file they're looking for.

```
❯ tree /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output/HelloWorldFunction
/tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctky6JmVn/output/HelloWorldFunction
└── hello-world
```

The `hello-world` program does have a main function:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

var (
    // DefaultHTTPGetAddress Default Address
    DefaultHTTPGetAddress = "https://checkip.amazonaws.com"

    // ErrNoIP No IP found in response
    ErrNoIP = errors.New("No IP in HTTP response")

    // ErrNon200Response non 200 status code in response
    ErrNon200Response = errors.New("Non 200 Response found")
)

func handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    str := "Hello World"
    str = exclaim(str)

    for i := 3; i < 30; i++ {
        str = exclaim(str)
        fmt.Println(str, "at", i)
    }

    
    resp, err := http.Get(DefaultHTTPGetAddress)
    if err != nil {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, err
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, ErrNon200Response
    }

    ip, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, err
    }

    if len(ip) == 0 {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, ErrNoIP
    }


    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        Body:       fmt.Sprintf("Hello, %v", string(ip)),
        StatusCode: 200,
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}

func exclaim(str string) string {
    return str + "!"
}
```

Note: I'm on a Mac, using the M1 chip(Arch: arm64) but the build-file is being executed for `x86-64`.

````
hello-world: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=O4tsTAbXATrthCbExZYS/IcUitw8QuK2KVYZ9ln5Y/QZl7mLeZv6TDrrYMwafh/81ITMlD5ZHrz3gae1BfY, with debug_info, not stripped``` 

Since it can find the file, Does this mean that the executor can't find the main?
````

Comment: Follow these two issues: [aws-toolkit](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/2020) and [sam-cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3283)